# Nonlinear programming problems in R

Tags: r

```
F = –y + 2x – ln (x/2)

s.t. –x – ln (x/2) + y ≤ 0

x ∈ [0.5, 1.4]

y ∈ {0, 1}

optimal solution: F∗ = 2.1247, x = 1.375, y = 1
```

How can I find this optimal solution for this nonlinear equation with optimization in R?

I tried this:

```
fn <- function(x,y){
f <- -x-log(x/2)+y
return(c(f))
}
fn2 <- function(z) crossprod(fn(z[1],z[2]) - c(0))
psoptim(c(1,1),fn2)
```

Comment: What is `z`? also, you don't need to use `c()` if it's just to include one element or vector.

Comment: @Phil, isn't `z` just the argument of the `fn2` function?

Comment: Have your checked the use of `library(nleqslv)`? See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48832731/solving-a-system-of-nonlinear-equations-in-r

Comment: @aiatay7n yes I checked but i must use pso library for solving this

Comment: @r2evans yes I misread

Answer (score 1):

There are several good [Python Nonlinear Programming packages](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/83/is-there-a-high-quality-nonlinear-programming-solver-for-python). One option is to use `reticulate` to run the Python function in R.

**Save as `script.py`**

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO()
x = m.Var(lb=0.5,ub=1.4)
y = m.Var(lb=0,ub=1,integer=True)
m.Equation(-x-m.log(x/2)+y<=0)
F = -y+2*x-m.log(x/2)
m.Minimize(F)
m.options.SOLVER=1
m.solve(disp=False)
print(m.options.OBJFCNVAL)
print(x.value[0])
print(y.value[0])
```

**Run code in `R`**

```r
library(reticulate)
py_run_file("script.py")
```

The script produces the result:

```
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :   4.379999998491257E-002 sec
 Objective      :    2.12446758455087     
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
 
2.1244675846
1.3748225282
1.0
```

The objective function is a little different than the comment: `optimal solution: F∗ = 2.1247, x = 1.375, y = 1`.